# Javascript shorthand

Tags: javascript, shorthand

If I can say:

```
var big = (x > 10) ? true : false;
```

instead of:

```
var big;
if (x > 10) {
    big = true;
}
else {
    big = false;
}
```

how do I make this similarly shorter?

```
var now = new Date

if (now.getHours() < 5) {
    return "late night pick me up";
}
else if (now.getHours() < 9) {
    return "breakfast";
}
else if (now.getHours() < 13) {
    return "lunch";
}
else if (now.getHours() < 17) {
    return "afternoon snak";
}
else {
    return "dinner";
}
```

Thanks a big bunch!

Comment: That's what I thought..if you delete your comment and make it an answer i will tick you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, without a bunch of messy nested ternary operators. The ternary operator is only good for one liners.

Comment: sorry everyone. Everyone's pretty much right, so the first answer got the tick.

Answer (score 9):

```
var now = new Date().getHours();

return now < 5 ? "late night pick me up" :
       now < 9 ? "breakfast" :
       now < 13 ? "lunch" :
       now < 17 ? "afternoon snak" : "dinner";
```

Comment: Why is this not being voted up?

This is the most general shorthand for this kind of problems, simple enough to use. And even if it occurs to you that ternary operator can be chained, it will probably not occur to you if you haven't used it, that the parentheses can be dropped from ``a ? b : (c ? d : e)``.

Answer (score 3):

You can't shorthand that particularly, personally I would just write it like this:

```
if (now.getHours() < 5) return "late night pick me up";
else if (now.getHours() < 9) return "breakfast";
else if (now.getHours() < 13) return "lunch";
else if (now.getHours() < 17) return "afternoon snak";
else return "dinner";
```

That's not too bad is it?

Comment: A slight variation: you can drop all the 'elses' completely, leaving just 'ifs' since each one results in a return statement.  Aside from less code/less typing, your conditional statements will all line up vertically making visual comparison between them even easier.

Comment: That's true in this particular case, particularly because of the 'return' operator, but some might argue that the 'else' aids legibility and that shouldn't be lost un-necessarily

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to, as arguably it would be less readable.  However, you could simply nest the ternary operator like so:

```
var now = (now.getHours() < 5) ? "late night pick me up" : ((now.getHours() < 9) ? "breakfast" : ((now.getHours() < 13) ? "lunch" : ((now.getHours() < 17) ? "afternoon snack" : "dinner")))));
```

I hope you can see why this isn't a good idea!

A longer, more complex condition like this generally needs multiple lines and good block separation to be easily understandable - and while you could arguably add line breaks, the standard `if-else` blocks are ultimately going to come out the winner at clearly expressing your intent.

Comment: yup i can see why :) its scary

Answer (score 2):

First, try `var big = x > 10;` instead of `var big = (x > 10) ? true : false;`

Second, you don't need if-else when you have return.

```
//looks  a little confusing, but you can move the return to line after ifs
var now = new Date  
if (now.getHours() < 5)  return "late night pick me up"; 
if (now.getHours() < 9)  return "breakfast";
if (now.getHours() < 13) return "lunch";
if (now.getHours() < 17) return "afternoon snak";
return "dinner";
```

Answer (score 1):

It will look quite messy:

```
return ((now.getHours() < 5)?"late night pick me up":
         ((now.getHours() < 9)?"breakfast":
            ((now.getHours() < 13)?"lunch":
               ((now.getHours() < 17)?"afternoon snack":
                  "dinner"
               )
            )
          )
       );
```

You have to remember to match parenthesis.

Comment: This is what i call, parenthesis Inception. A level more and code is in Limbo :-)

Comment: @Satish, the last time i had to match up parenthesis was in a `cLisp` class

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a switch statement:

```
switch(true)
{
case (now.getHours() < 5):
  return "late night pick me up";
  break;
case (now.getHours() < 9):
  return "breakfast";
  break;  //etc...
default:
  return "dinner";
}
```

Comment: Was just about to write exactly the same thing.

Comment: +1 - thanks for the correction, I made edits to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this in search for something else. Here's a little shorthand trick using logical operators and abusing the fact string literals are truthy =]

```
var hr = new Date().getHours();

return hr < 5 && 'late night pick me up' 
    || hr < 9 && 'breakfast' 
    || hr < 13 && 'lunch' 
    || hr < 17 && 'afternoon snack' 
    || 'dinner';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a table to replicate functionality:

```
var now = new Date();
var meals = [
    "late night pick me up",
    "breakfast",
    "lunch",
    "afernoon snack",
    "dinner"];
return meals[parseInt(now.getHours()-4)/4];
```

Comment: i like this one too but its more like an alternative representation and making things shorter

Comment: and if `now.getHours() == 13`, you cannot have decimal keys in an array (`hours[9/4]`)

Comment: Forgot about JS's division behavior. Updated and fixed.

Comment: Even I was tempted to write a code like this, but I realized it doesn't work.